# Remove Cookies by clicking on button - Web Extension API

Tags: javascript, cookies, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm dealing first time with Firefox Web Extension API. I want to remove all cookies of example.com by clicking on a button. I have the following code but doesn't get any result.

background.js

```
function onRemoved(cookie) {
  console.log(`Removed: ${cookie}`);
}

function onError(error) {
  console.log(`Error removing cookie: ${error}`);
}

function removeCookie() {
  var removing = browser.cookies.remove({
    url: "example.com"
  });
  removing.then(onRemoved, onError);
}

browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(removeCookie);
```

manifest.json

```
{

 "description": "RemoveCookie",
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "name": "remove-cookies",
 "version": "1.0",
 "icons": {
 "48": "icons/icon.png"
 },

"background": {
 "scripts": ["background.js"]
},

"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "icons/icon.png",
  "default_title": "Remove Cookie!"
},

"permissions": [
 "*://*.example.com/*",
 "cookies"
]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/remove

> The remove() method of the cookies API deletes a cookie, given its name and URL.

This means you also need to specify the `name` parameter.

Moreover, the `url` parameter must include the protocol or the promise will just resolve with `null` (meaning no cookie can be found).

> If a cookie matching the details parameter could not be found, the promise is fulfilled with null.

---

That being said, you can use `browser.cookies.getAll` to get all the cookies for a given URL and then delete each cookie given its name:

```
function onRemoved(cookies) {
  console.log('Removed', cookies);
}

function onError(error) {
  console.log(`Error removing cookie: ${error}`);
}

function removeCookie() {
  var url = "http://example.com"; // NOTE the full url including protocol
  browser.cookies.getAll({ url: url })
  .then(function(cookies) {
    return Promise.all(cookies.map(function(cookie) {
      return browser.cookies.remove({ url: url, name: cookie.name });
    }));
  })
  .then(onRemoved, onError);
}

browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(removeCookie);
```

Comment: @HeScm Great! Consider accepting the answer if it worked for you